# How to configure and validate s3 lifecycle with glacier for 1 to days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have ask to move s3 objects to Glacier post 90days. Now i am doing the poc for 1 day and created lifecyle policies and applied and details are

1. Created s3 bucket, added few objects
2. Created the lifecycle policy by selecting the "Glacier instant Retriveal" by selecting 1day and saved the rules.
3. Created Glacier Valut on that account  and saved it.
   Now Questions are
4. How to configure Valut with s3 buckets , is there 1 to 1 configuration, by default s3 will find the Valut (right now only one) if many how to mention and where to mention.
5. Post creation of lifecycle rules and what other things mandatory to run the rules every day 00:00:00 hrs? or based on uploaded objects has to completed 24hrs cycle and then it will pick by the rules.
6. My s3 rules are active and but its not run? how to determine the rules are running and we have succefully configured  s3-Glacier for 1 day to 90days.
   4.There are few youtube example with older version of AWS UI. do we have any new version or am i missing something to make it work

Regards
Prasanna
Edinburgh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two "Glacier" services on AWS:

- The 'original' Amazon Glacier which uses Vaults and Archives: It is slow, difficult to use and typically should be avoided.
- The "Glacier" **storage classes in Amazon S3** that move objects to Glacier in the background, but they still appear in Amazon S3 as normal objects (but with a different storage class and time limitations on access). These storage classes are also **cheaper than the 'original' Amazon Glacier** should typically should always be the ones you use.

If you are using Lifecycle Policies in Amazon S3, then objects will be moved to the **Glacier Storage Class**. They do not involve Vaults or Archives. (Well, they do go into vaults, but those vaults are managed by S3 and are not visible in your AWS Account.)

Lifecycle rules can sometimes take 24-48 hours to run.